# PHP Class names from variables

Tags: php

Can  I dynamically name a class?

I have written a process which calls about 6 pages that generate pdfs through tcpdf.
They all use the same header page which makes a class.

```
class myPDF extends TCPDF {
```

the problem is when i run my script I get Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class myPDF in
after the first page is done.

I understand why but am at a loss how to deal with it.

calling it only once is no good as it holds a function which looks at page specific variables.

I also don't think I can UNdeclare it in anyway.

Once way would be to change the class name for each include but not sure how to make the class name a variable?

ie class $newname

Any ideas

S

Added this

```
class myPDF extends TCPDF {
public function Header () {

global $title;
global $client;
global $host;


$oMulticell->multiCell(266,8, "<s1>$title&nbsp;     Client:</s1> <s2>$client</s2>     <s1>Host:</s1> <s2>$host</s2>     <s1>Currency:</s1> <s2>$currency</s2>     <s1>Reporting Period:</s1> <s2>$start_date_rep to $end_date_rep</s2>", 'TB');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`include_once();` should fix your problem.

Comment: each time i run an include it uses page specific variables inside the class - if I use it once - it doesnt look to the new variables

Comment: Your code should be fine if you make sure that wherever you include the myPDF class or TCPDF class, you change `include` to `include_once`. The reason it works with one include is because each subsequent include is trying to redefine `myPDF`, whereas if you instead do `include_once` then it won't have that issue! Try that and it should be fixed. :)

Edit: do you really need to generate those page specific variables inside the class?

Comment: ok emma - i had to muck about with some includes and put the class in its own page but you were completely right.

Do I need to generate within the class - not sure but i am following tcpdf examples which did so . No problem for a single pdf but one after the other driven from a master page caused my issue.

thanks for the guidance

Comment: Ideally, you should just put a class in its own php file, with nothing but just that class in there -- this is one reason why you should do that. Also I've got a job, thanks though lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Class definition has to be parsable in compile-time, and not in run-time. You can't make a "dynamic" class name.